# Are there existing patterns for forwarding an image to email from in app?

Tags: design-patterns, mobile-application, sharing

I am working on an app where one of the final steps in the signup process requires that users provide information displayed on screen to their employer; they can either go to their email and forward the data we sent them or they can screenshot that same data in app and provide it to their employer.

I want to know if anyone is aware of an existing pattern that would allow users to email or message that information directly from in app to their employer, without having to switch to their email or take a screenshot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should talk to your developers occasionally because they will tell you about potential solutions such as:

- setup an API endpoint that receives the information from app (perhaps your API already has the information from earlier activities) and email from your server.
- generate the image, text file, pdf, whatever programmatically then send it. Offscreen rendering is an option there.
- upload the data to a cloud service and share from there.
- use a 3rd party library to send email directly from the app.